# jQuery selecting top level element text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that has the section `Store` this has a submenu of categories `Printers` `Keyboards` and under these categories they have their own sub categories.

What I am trying to do is select the top level categories that are `Printers` `Keyboards` just using jQuery into an `Array`.

When I use the following it prints out `["Printers", "Color", "Black/White", "Dual", "Keyboards", "Wired", "Wireless", "Touchscreen"]` This is more than I need for now, could someone help me

Check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/Mkv9q/)

**jQuery**

```
var optionTexts = [];
$('.main-menu ul li a:contains("Store")').parent().find('.sub-menu > li a').each(function(){
        optionTexts.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(optionTexts);
```

Comment: You should probably find next `a` after `li` like this one: `.find('.sub-menu > li > a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT I looked at your fiddle a bit more closeley and changed the way the right "a" tag is found:

`'.sub-menu > li > ul > li > a'`  will do it (I checked it in your jsfiddle):

```
$('.main-menu ul li a:contains("Store")').parent().find('.sub-menu > li > ul > li > a').each(function(){
    optionTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```

The way you did it, every a underneath the "ul.sub-menu" is selected - also those that are nested in children and grandchildren of "ul.sub-menu".

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for something like this

```
var optionTexts = [];
$('.main-menu ul li a:contains("Store")').parent().find('.sub-menu').parent('li').each(function(){
    optionTexts.push($(this).children('a').text());
});
console.log(optionTexts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Edit your code like this, its worked :

```
$(function () {
    $(".check").on('click', function () {
        var optionTexts = [];
        $('.list > ul > li > a').each(function () {
            optionTexts.push($(this).text());
        });
        c(optionTexts);
    });
});
```

output : Printers, Keyboards

Check it FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/Mkv9q/16/